# Problems performing an asynchronous search (WPF/C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, uwp, task

I am currently making a search system for UWP packages, the idea is that by typing in the TextBox will show the results that match the text in a ListBox.

The idea I have is to create a task that filters the packages that match the search when the text has changed.

```
private async void OnSearchBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
     if (searchBox.Text != "")
     {
        tokenSource = new();
        token = tokenSource.Token;
        await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
                appsListBox.ItemsSource = (from Package package in packageManager.FindPackagesForUser("")
                                          where
                                             package.DisplayName.ToLower().Contains(searchBox.Text.ToLower())
                                          select package);
                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Task canceled");
        }, DispatcherPriority.Background, token);
    }
}
```

From then on, when the text keeps changing, cancel the previous task in case it has not been completed yet, to make way for the new task to be created.

```
private void OnSearchBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    if (tokenSource != null)
        tokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

In short "PreviewTextInput" would cancel the task that is running, in case there is one. Then "TextChanged" would create a new search task with the current text, and so on until you stop entering text for a moment so that "TextChanged" can finish its final task and display its results.

I am currently getting the error shown in the image, I would like to know if anyone can help me, either by giving me some guidance on how to fix that error, or some more optimal way to do what I have described above. [image]

Comment: Dispatcher.InvokeAsync might not be doing what you think. It just schedules the callback Action for later execution on the UI thread. You may want to take a look at Task.Run.

Answer (score -1):

Why use async? How about below code?

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SearchDataGrid
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<Person> list = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            list.Add(new Person { ID = 1, Name = "Tom", Age = "11" });
            list.Add(new Person { ID = 2, Name = "Smith", Age = "22" });
            list.Add(new Person { ID = 3, Name = "Jimin", Age = "33" });
            list.Add(new Person { ID = 4, Name = "John", Age = "44" });

            dataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
        }

        private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = list.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(tb.Text));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using async is highly recommended so as to not freeze the GUI and keep the app responsive.